# Installin PHP mail on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: php, email, ubuntu, postfix-mta

I've installed LAMP on my local machine and I'm now looking to add PHP mail, however I'm not having much luck.

I've installed postfix and my /etc/postfix/main.cf looks like the following:

```
myhostname = my_computer_name (is this ok?)
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = my_domain_name, my_computer_name, localhost.localdomain, localhost
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm missing? Is myhostname supposed to be my computers name or something else? Same with mydestination. Does it need a relayhost?

Cheers

Comment: I thought php mail was a module of php?

Comment: I'm not sure, however if I've just put an if/else statement around the mail function and it did return a success however in the mail log it says the connection timed out. Will this be something at the mail servers end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a php info to see whats installed

http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php

Follow a real back to basics example like this (to determine if it is code-based or configuration based)

```
<?php
$to = "somebody@example.com";
$subject = "My subject";
$txt = "Hello world!";
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com" . "\r\n" .
"CC: somebodyelse@example.com";

mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
?>
```

In my experience it usually works out of the box, you might have to investigate other things like this link here:

http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/Configure_PHP_to_Use_a_Local_Mail_Server_for_Sending_Mail.htm

Answer (score 0):

php mail use your system MTA (Mail Transfer Agent), it is Postfix in your case. So you have to configure correctly postfix first. It is not easy to configure because when your server send an email, the recipient mail server can block it (antispam filter) for many reason and one for the reason is your hostname not matching your server ip.